# Ubuntu 22.04 - Built-in power settings vs. TLP

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, 22.04, tlp

I've just switched from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and noticed the new version offers power management settings, to an extent.

I suppose one shouldn't run `tlp` alongside it, but choose one or the other?
And if that's so, which one should be chosen?

I'd be inclined to go with the default one, but `tlp` seems more mature. The default power manager doesn't even seem to apply different profiles for when the computer is plugged in or off. For laptops, that is a deal-breaker

Are my assessments correct, and if so, what should be done about them?

Comment: I'm surely inclined to use only the native settings. I've had very bad experiences with TLP in the past.

Comment: I'd be as well, but having to manually switch the performance settings every time I plug or unplug my machine is unthinkable

Comment: TLPUI is not working in ubuntu 22.04 the PPA source does not work

Answer (score 2):

I have a Thinkpad and after reading [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/qpaa4g/tlp_vs_powerprofilesdaemon/hjsexco/?context=3) I preferred to use TLP instead of power-profiles-daemon.