How to make the power statistics persistent between reboots?
My laptop battery drains within a few minutes.
If have found that my power statistics are cleared after reboot.
I suspect that the reason why my laptop battery drains so fast,
is because my laptop makes a wrong estimation of the battery percentage.
Can someone explain to me how to make the power statistic persistent between reboots?
Please let me know if you suspect another problem.
laptop specs:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: HP Laptop 15s-eq1xxx
Kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic
Uptime: 13 mins
Packages: 2252 (dpkg), 13 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.2.21
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME 46.0
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: rose-pine-gtk [GTK2/3]
Icons: rose-pine-icons [GTK2/3]
Terminal: tmux
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics (8) @ 2.000GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX Vega 6
Memory: 1976MiB / 15346MiB

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent:
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE=Battery
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=153
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11340000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=10564000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=17055000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=17055000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=5443000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=31
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=Primary
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Hewlett-Packard
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=


How old is the laptop? I had a HP laptop whose battery was getting drained within 10 minutes after three years of heavy use. The solution was to replace the battery

It might be worthwhile checking out TLP: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404546/ubuntu-22-04-built-in-power-settings-vs-tlp

My laptop is a few years old, but before the clean install (a couple of weeks ago), the battery would last for an hour or 2.
